# How to work with cgal circulators?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal, delaunay

I'm trying to make delaunay triangulation of point set, find nearest point to input point, and get it's incident vertices, but somehow following code doesn't work.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <fstream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Triangulation;
typedef Triangulation::Edge_iterator Edge_iterator;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_circulator Vertex_circulator;
int main( )
{
  std::ifstream in("data.txt");
  assert(in);
  std::istream_iterator<Point> begin(in);
  std::istream_iterator<Point> end;
  Triangulation T;
  T.insert(begin, end);
  std::cout << T.number_of_vertices() <<std::endl;
  Vertex_handle handle = T.nearest_vertex(Point(1, 1));
  std::cout << handle->point() << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"incidents: \n" << std::endl;
  Vertex_circulator circulator = T.incident_vertices(handle), done(circulator);
  do
    {
      std::cout << circulator->point() << std::endl;
    } while(++circulator != done);
  return 0;
}
```

For example if data.txt is

```
2 3
1 1
1 0
```

output is

```
3
1 1
incidents:

1 0
2 3
2.02461e-307 6.94896e-308
```

Why do I have last line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2D triangulations of CGAL have an infinite vertex connected to all the vertices of the convex hull (see the [user manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html) for details).

You can use the [is_infinite](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html#a621089aa72b912856d565203dee1777b) function to test if a simplex is infinite.